# Filtra en el formulario solo por los elementos que aparecen y no por todos los existentes

Tags: javascript, angular, filtro, pipe, ngfor

tengo un formulario donde al escribir me aparece segun coindidencias nombres de empresas que me cargan de una base de datos. Con el metodo slice(0,5) ya he conseguido que me aparezcan  las 5 primeras, pero al filtrar por nombre no encuentra coincidencias ya que solo me buscan por esas 5 primera. Yo lo que estoy intentando es que me muestre solo 5 nombres y al escribir me haga la busqueda de todos los nombres existentes, pero que solo lo vaya mostrando de 5 en 5 ya que sino la busqueda se vuelve muy lenta por tener que recuperar una cantidad de datos elevada. Os dejo el codigo que tengo y os pregunto si lo que tengo que hacer es añadirle algo mas al *ngfor. gracias.

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input type="text" formControlName="cliente"  matInput
                      [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
                  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers.slice(0,5)|  filtro: textSearch:'name'"
                       [value]="customer.name" (onSelectionChange)="selectCustomer(customer)">
                          {{customer.name}}
                      </mat-option>
                  </mat-autocomplete>
              </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Desde donde estas trayendo los datos, ¿una api?, con base de datos ¿sql? ¿noSql? ¿graphql? Lo mejor que puedes hacer es limitar el numero de resultados allí, en el backend y no enredarte con esto en el frondend

Comment: Los datos mediante una api y el backend me lo devuelve de una base de datos noSql. Pero en el backend no tengo muy claro como hacer esto. Pensaba que sería mas facil desde el front.

Comment: Es que he visto un ejemplo que va filtrando y le va cambiando los resultados de la lista  segun lo que se va escribiendo, pero nunca mostrando mas de 5 en la lista. Se vuelve dinamica la lista.

Comment: Si tu estas desarrollando el backend, te aconsejo que hagas lo que te digo, limita el numero de resultados,  con un máximo de 5, y mediante eventos `keyup` o `input` solicita las coincidencias y muestra las

Comment: Es lo mejor, que vaya en el backend, porque no se me ocurre una buena manera para que hagas esto en el frond

Comment: Muchas gracias Josbert, creo que haré un poc. almacenado para esto entonces. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he solucionado por si algun dia os pasa se soluciona añadiendole el metodo slice(0,5) a la lista en el pipe y no en el html como se puede ver en el trozo de codigo que he puesto de ejemplo en este post.  teniendo que ser de la siguiente manera.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filtro'
})
export class FiltroPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(arr: any[], texto: string, columna: string): any[] {

     if( texto === ''){
      return;
    } 
    
    texto = texto.toLowerCase();   

   return arr.filter(item =>{
     if(item[columna] != null)
      return item[columna].toLowerCase().includes(texto);   
    }).slice(0,5);
```